# Using S3 instead of Cassandra/DynamoDB (Case Use)

Tags: http, amazon-s3, cassandra, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

Has any one had any experience Using S3 in such manner, would greatly help in my pursuit to accomplish or scrap this task.

**Plan**

1. Insert 400-800 Objects/Second into S3 1.5kb-2kb each. 
   Sent as **Key**(UUID Hash), **Payload**({key:value}). 
   This has been tested with Artillery http testing and seems to be working well but i have doubts.
2. Extract Object from S3 Approximately 40-60 Objects every 10 seconds
3. Have SQS Messages as a backup Mechanism, to be able to divert failed S3 inserts into SQS.
4. Have SQS Messages retry to insert into S3 again within 30 seconds or other option.

**The files sent to s3 will have a minimum delay of 15 minutes before inserted records will be read. Which leads me to peace of mind not having an issue if latency is high.**

Reason to try this kind of implementation and not Cassandra or DynamoDB is simple...

Cassandra, its hell to manage and can get quiet expensive. (been working with consultants and its a mess.)
DynamoDB is next solution if this doesn't workout, I like the idea that s3 is unlimited storage and much cheaper of course.

Any response, suggestions, comments will be appreciated!

Comment: how will S3 data be consumed? is it necessary that each S3 file contains one payload- can it have batched data?

Comment: At this point it must be non batched, because uuid (key) is created on the fly as an identifier of another (external) system.